# バッチファイルの引数を出力ファイルに追記していくにはどうすればいいでしょうか。

Tags: batch-file

バッチファイルの引数を出力ファイルに追記していくにはどうすればいいでしょうか。

例えば、parameterを取得して追記していくバッチファイルhoge.batがあるとします。

```
cd C:Program Files (x86)¥hogehoge¥hoge.exe
hoge.exe getparameter >> parameter.log
```

結果は

```
023
```

と値だけが返されるとします。

```
hoge.bat 1
```

と引数をつけて実行した場合
結果を

```
1,023
```

と出力できるよう、引数を取得してログに出力する方法を知りたいです。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@echo off
set /P dummy=%1, <NUL >>parameter.log
cd C:Program Files (x86)¥hogehoge¥hoge.exe
hoge.exe getparameter >> parameter.log
```

のようにすればいいかと思います。
バッチファイルの引数は%1で取得できますが、
単に`echo %1,` のようにすると改行されてしまうので、
[こちらのブログ](http://piyopiyocs.blog115.fc2.com/blog-entry-591.html)の方法(`set /P`を使う)を使わせて貰いました。